# How can I test how my websites render on Mobile Safari without buying an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, emulation, mobile-safari

All the "emulators" I've found via google are simply a skin on top of Safari desktop or use your OS's default browser :( I borrowed my friends iPhone and noticed the CSS for a pure CSS drop-down menu doesn't render properly and you can't click the links, yet it renders properly on Safari desktop and every other browser even Internet Explorer 6 and 7. In other words the site is unnavigable on the iPhone. How can I test the Safari Mobile rendering engine without buying an iPhone?

edit: Okay it appears there is an iPhone simulator for Mac. I will just see if an OSX image will dual-boot on another harddrive partition of my laptop, if not I'll scrounge for a used iPod Touch though I generally disdain possessing superfluous peripherals.

Comment: Borrow a friend's? Buy an iPod Touch instead? Use the simulator on a mac (but if you had a mac you could just use DashCode to make it much easier).

Comment: Its often a good idea to actually have a device if you are programming for it because the runtime performance could sometimes be quite surprising....

Comment: I run OS X on a virtual machine for testing (Virtualbox; VMware can do it too). It takes a little bit of hacking about, and it'll need a decent processor, with hardware virtualisation available, but it works without having to clutter the place up with more unwanted computers.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 5):

Either use a Mac and run the iPhone Simulator, or get an old iPod touch, which isn't that expensive.

Comment: +1 for thinking further outside the box. I never considered an iPod Touch. I would +1 again if I could ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it depends on rollover of any sort then I think you've discovered the problem.

Is purchasing a mac mini within your budget? Then you could load the emulater in XCode.

Comment: Interesting according to this site:
http://www.justtwonerds.com/2010/02/24/free-css-dropdown-menu-with-iphone-quick-tip/

adding onmouseover=”" inside an element  will allow the hover CSS events to perform as intended on the iPhone even if onmouseover is blank, otherwise they will be ignored by default. I'll have to try that.