# Iphone/Ipad emulator for windows

Tags: ios-simulator, emulation, sencha-touch

I want to getting flexible with Sencha Touch. I write my codes and viewing on Google Chrome well but I am searching an Ipad and Iphone simulator/emulator runs on Windows. I want to look and feel my codes in Ipad and IPhone. Is there any simulator/emulator available for Windows?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** There is no emulator or simulator for Windows. However PhoneGap is available on Mac OS and really made great improvements by months. If you use Mac OS and need something like this I strongly recommend PhoneGap. If you need this tool in Windows, probably there is no other way then install Mac OS a virtual machine on Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test on the IPhone without having access to one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928955/how-to-test-on-the-iphone-without-having-access-to-one) and [How can I test how my websites render on Mobile Safari without buying an iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979000/how-can-i-test-how-my-websites-render-on-mobile-safari-without-buying-an-iphone)

Comment: @jleedev. This is not duplicated with your provided link because I am searching an emulator for window also there is no work around solution in linked question.

Comment: @jleedev. did you read my question and check the links. Be serious.

Comment: I am serious (and don’t call me Shirley). The answers to those questions indicate that you can use the simulator on OS X, or you can use an iPod Touch, or you can use Safari on the PC for a limited experience.

Comment: Yeah, you are serious, sure, but I could not get my answer still. I saw in a conference one is using an ipad emulator with his laptop that runs on Windows 7. So, I am searching this tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be thinking of the PhoneGap Simulator. It's an Adobe Air app so it will run on anything and while It's meant to be used with the hybrid framework, Phonegap, you can put any URL into the app. It is helpful for debugging web based apps, but it may not be workable for your needs.

Alas, they do not have a device profile for the iPad.